# Хранение множества продуктов

Tags: java, hibernate

У меня есть база данных и 3 таблицы: ProductEntity, OrderEntity и ProductInOrder

```
@Entity
public class ProductEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private long price;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productEntity")
    private List<ProductInOrder> productInOrder;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(long price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<ProductInOrder> getProductInOrder() {
        return productInOrder;
    }

    public void setProductInOrder(List<ProductInOrder> productInOrder) {
        this.productInOrder = productInOrder;
    }


@Entity
public class OrderEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="orderEntity")
    private List<ProductInOrder> productInOrder;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<ProductInOrder> getProductInOrder() {
        return productInOrder;
    }

    public void setProductInOrder(List<ProductInOrder> productInOrder) {
        this.productInOrder = productInOrder;
    }  
}

@Entity
public class ProductInOrder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private OrderEntity orderEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    private ProductEntity productEntity;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public OrderEntity getOrderEntity() {
        return orderEntity;
    }

    public void setOrderEntity(OrderEntity orderEntity) {
        this.orderEntity = orderEntity;
    }

    public ProductEntity getProductEntity() {
        return productEntity;
    }

    public void setProductEntity(ProductEntity productEntity) {
        this.productEntity = productEntity;
    }
}
```

И собственно вопрос. Как с помощью hibernate мне отобразить в базе данных, что у одного заказа может быть несколько товаров. Как это отобразить в базе данных для сущности ProductInOrder? В ней хранится только id той той сущности, которая была последней добавлена через persist.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу понять, как лучше сделать. Что бы в поле productentity_id хранились id всех товаров, которые я добавил в так называемую корзину или что бы для каждого товара была отдельная строка в таблице ProductInOrder?
А вот метод в ejb, которым я пытаюсь добавить товары в заказ:

```
public void createOrder(List<Product> list) {
        OrderEntity orderEntity = new OrderEntity();
        entityManager.persist(orderEntity);
        ProductInOrder productInOrder = new ProductInOrder();
        productInOrder.setOrderEntity(orderEntity);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            ProductEntity productEntity = entityManager.find(ProductEntity.class, list.get(i).getId());
            if (productEntity == null) {
                continue;
            }
            productInOrder.setProductEntity(productEntity);

        }
        entityManager.persist(productInOrder);
    }
```

Я недавно начал изучать javaee и пытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то у вас связь многие ко многим и вы создали лишнюю сущность в коде. И когда вы достанете нужный продукт или нужный заказ, то внутри каждой сущности будет set заказов или товаров соответсвенно

Comment: Это связь многие ко многим, просто я вручную создал промежуточную таблицу через сущность ProductInOrder. Мне лучше удалить эту сущность и поставить аннотации @ManyToMany?

Comment: То что создали таблицу, это правильно, но сущность лишняя, вам нужно организовать многие ко многим и у вас останется всего две сущности...с ними и легче работать

Answer (score 0):

```
Вот решение вашей задачи:

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "orders_products",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_order")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_product")}
    )
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();

    public Order() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        products.add(product);
        product.getOrders().add(this);
    }

    public void removeProduct(Product product) {
        products.add(product);
        product.getOrders().add(this);
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();

    public Product() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(Set<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

}

@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Integer> {
}

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer> {
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Product product1 = new Product();
        product1.setName("product1");
        product1 = productRepository.save(product1);

        Order order1 = new Order();
        order1.setName("order1");
        order1.addProduct(product1);
        orderRepository.save(order1);

        System.out.println(orderRepository.findAll());
        System.out.println(productRepository.findAll());
    }

}
```